# regex remove line breaks after any but specific characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file with semicolons separator and I need to remove all the line breaks after any character but `;` and `"`.

I have succeeded in finding positions but removing line breaks doesn't seem to work.

What I have:

```
100138;"Some data";"AB";"My text goes here";
100139;"Some data 2";"CH";"My text goes here";
100140;"Some data 3";"CH";"My text goes here
And it has new line here
But it is still part of quoted data
and ends here";
100141;"Some data 4";"CH";"Another nice text without semicolon"enter
```

What I need:

```
100138;"Some data";"AB";"My text goes here";
100139;"Some data 2";"CH";"My text goes here";
100140;"Some data 3";"CH";"My text goes here And it has new line here But it is still part of quoted data and ends here";
100141;"Some data 4";"CH";"Another nice text without semicolon"enter
```

I used `(?<=[^("|;)])$` to find it but `\n` doesn't seem to change anything. 
I use notepad++ for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(?<=[^;])(?<=[^"])\R`

- `$` Find end of line
- `(?<=[^;])` Must not end with `;`
- `(?<=[^"])` Must not end with `"`
- `\R` Match linebreak character(s)

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. It selects the end of every single line than, not just the ones I want

Comment: Now the selection works, but replacing outpoot no changes. I have tried with blank value, \1 and blankspace but nothing worked

Comment: I have solved this at last. The problem was I guess that my line breaks were composed on different ways. Anyway what I did was to erase all line breaks, to have my file in one line and than I used another regex to brake it before [0-9]{6}; this worked fine! thanks for your advice anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<![;"])\R`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

This will replace all linebreaks that aren't preceeded by `;` nor `"`.

Comment: Yes, that should work in normal situation. Please check my last comment in previous answer where I explained what I think had happened. Anyway, thank you for the help!

Comment: @bigcat: It should work for any kind of linebreak, that's the purpose of `\R`

Comment: Yes I know the purpose of R, but in my case that just didn't work. I have no idea why! Anyway I managed to do it the way I described, and once more thanks for the help!